# Rendering an image on a Java-Backend then displaying it in the Frontend

Tags: javascript, java, image, frontend, spark-java

My goal is to have a node-editor in the frontend which passes information on how data is supposed to be rendered as an image to the backend, where the heavy lifting is done, resulting in an image which is then displayed in the browser again.

To achieve this, I have a Java Spark-Route looking like this:

```
    post("/render", (req, res) -> {

      Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
      ResponsePojo response = gson.fromJson(req.body(), ResponsePojo.class);

      BufferedImage bi = render(response);


      // Write the image data to the response output stream
      try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        ImageIO.write(bi, "jpeg", baos);
        res.raw().getOutputStream().write(baos.toByteArray());
        res.raw().getOutputStream().flush();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }


      res.type("image/jpeg");
      res.status(200);

      return res;
    });
```

Calling this route looks like this:

```
  // Send the request using the fetch() method
  fetch(RENDER_URL, requestOptions)
    .then(response => {
      //const blob = streamToBlob(response.body, 'jpeg');

      let data;
      let url;

      response.blob().then(blobResponse => {
        data = blobResponse;
      })

      url = URL.createObjectURL(data);
    })
```

This call results in the following error:

```
Error occurred during request: TypeError: URL.createObjectURL: Argument 1 is not valid for any of the 1-argument overloads.
```

I've also taken a look at the following npm module: https://github.com/feross/stream-to-blob

Which results in the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: stream.on is not a function
    streamToBlob2 index.js:13
    streamToBlob2 index.js:10
    sendRenderRequest index.js:95
```

What's confusing to me is that the errors suggest to me that I'm not in fact working with a ReadableStream, however if I console.log() the response.body I do get:

`Response.body received: ReadableStream { locked: false }`

Looking forward to any and all help, thanks in advance for your time and sorry for any obvious oversights, I'm still learning!

Comment: What does this have to do with java?

Comment: The rendering of the image on the backend is done in Java (first code block) and I'm not entirely certain if the creation of the response is correct.

Comment: Right, but either the problem is with java (which you test by directly pointing a browser, or curl or something) at its URL and check whether the response is a real image, and if it's not: this is just a java question, no need for anything else. Or if it works fine, this has nothing to do with java, and it's a question about that fetch block. So: _test that now_ because you're still the one driving. Fire up your browser and try to load whatever url you have in `RENDER_URL`. Does it work? Cool, you know the problem is on the JS side now. Does it not? Cool, it's on the Java side.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you for your time and effort

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're going to at the very least need to fix that JS, because if you're using `then` on a promise, *all the code* that has to subsequently kick in has to either be inside that `then` handler, or be in function(s) that are called from inside that `then` handler, or be somewhere in the subsequent `then` chain. The following code does not work:

```
let data;

response.blob().then(blobResponse => {
  data = blobResponse;
})

url = URL.createObjectURL(data);
```

because your `url = ...` doesn't wait for anything: `response.blob()` is a promise, and so we immediately move on to `url = ...` without waiting, and at *some unknown time in the future*, that `then` handler will kick in.

So: give the MDN ["Using Promises"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) a read, and move all the code that depends on the result of that `then` *into* the handler. Or, alternatively, mark your context as `async` so that you can use the `await` keyword instead of having to chain `then` handlers.